# directshow transform filter wrapper

Tags: c++, directshow

any one know a way to wrap direct show transform filters? i need to use a directshow transform filter, the source code of filter is not accessible, and my application developed in Media foundation, i didn't find any way to use DS filters in MF, any suggestion?

Something like this: [Direct Show Native Wrapper](http://oss.netfarm.it/dsnative/).

Answer (score 0):

Filters are not expected to operate outside of graphs, you will need a minimal graph over the filter. Since transformation filters typically have both inputs and outputs, the graph will include some source, the transformation itself and some sink filter (which can be [Sample Grabber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) filter and [Null Renderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) filters together - a typical use case).

All together this would be a wrapper over transformation filter.